# Excel - dates in column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Probably a simple question, but I can't find an answer. 
In the first column of Excel I need simple dates:

```
1.12.2019
2.12.2019
3.12.2019
4.12.2019
...
```

How can I automate this not to typing every date?

Comment: Are the dates you're showing month.day.year or day.month.year?  Also, in your locale, is a period recognized as a date separator?

Comment: Enter first 2 dates. Select both cells. Drag them Down. Method fills dragged region using arithmetic progression and is workable for numbers and dates. For string values which's postfix is an integer it is enough to drag one value (for decimals, decimal part is treated as a separate integer, for negative numbers dragged up the values are increased till zero the are decreased back).

Comment: @fixer1234: yes, in our locale settings, a period is a date separator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

1. Type date 2019-12-1 in A1
2. Change the A1 Cell format to Custom format: d.mm.yyyy
3. Drag down:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's it :-)